# Regular expression to check whether varchar can be converted to bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have a varchar(25) field col1 in sql. col1 can have a-z & digits only. I have to find out whether col1 can be converted into BIGINT. if that is convertibale(has only digits and is less than < 2^63-1) then return true else false.

I was able to write only first condition.

```
SELECT CASE patindex ('%[a-zA-Z]%',col1) = 0 THEN 'false' else 'True' END FROM Table
```

Can someone help me to write second condition

Comment: Isn't there a function isnumeric in SQL Server?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I am using SQLServer 2012. Thanks I got the solution  from @a_horse_with_no_name.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 onwards you could use [TRY_PARSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx);

```
SELECT CASE WHEN try_parse(col1 as bigint) is null THEN 'false' else 'True' END FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
ISNUMERIC(col1) = 1 AND col1 BETWEEN
-9223372036854775808 AND 9223372036854775807 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
```

And if you do not like number then ...

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
ISNUMERIC(col1) = 1 AND col1 BETWEEN
(POWER(CAST(2 AS BIGINT),CAST(62 AS BIGINT))-1)* (-2)-2 AND (POWER(CAST(2 AS BIGINT),CAST(62 AS BIGINT))-1)* 2 +1THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
```

It is ugly, but try_parse is not working in <2012 versions

Comment: SELECT ISNUMERIC(85271242929748659648531480139083) returns 1. ISNUMERIC just checks whether it contains any alphanumeric character or not

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 SELECT 
        CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(bigint, 'rtew53523523') IS NULL 
        THEN 'Casting failed for bigint'
        ELSE 'Cast succeeded for bigint'
    END AS Result;
```